# Obj-C, why should I use the Avfoundation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I've got some problems IN MY APP, some people don't hear sound. I'm using mp3 files and the Audiotoolbox library.

Can someone if I should use the avfoundation or whether the audiotoolbox library is better ?

Comment: Maybe those people have the "mute" mode turned on. Even in the mute mode, the Youtube app and the iPod apps work, so it's quite confusing  sometimes. I once wrote to a developer of a game why it doesn't work on my iPad, and turned out my iPad was in the mute mode :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try playing MP3 file as below:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             
else 
    [audioPlayer play];
```

AudioToolbox is specifically for SystemSound and AVAudioPlayer of AVFoundation is for sounds included in our app..

Comment: Its not that AVFoundation is better or AudioToolbox.. but its your requirement and Both frameworks have their own quality... For more reference go to Apple's Documentation of both...

Answer (score 0):

You can refer a good sample code of AV Foundation: [AVSimplePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVSimplePlayerOSX/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011060)